I want to build a simple wooden outhouse but the ground is soft - how to make sure it's stable?
The old outhouse at our rural property has been slowly collapsing for years already. The two problems with it are rotting wood at the base, and soft ground which has resulted in one side slowly sinking down.
We have some old wood lying around, safely stored in dry place, so I thought I'd try and make a new one. Should be an interesting and educational experience.
But I'm wondering about the whole "sinking into soft ground" problem. How can I prevent that?
Besides wood I also have some old porous concrete blocks (I think it could be AAC or some other kind of foam concrete, but I'm not sure) and some old bricks. Both are over 30 years old. Maybe even closer to 50, hard to say. I could maybe try to put those underneath the outhouse, but I'm wondering if they could then sink themselves because of their weight? What I laid them flat?
And what are some alternatives? I'd like to keep it as low-tech and fast as possible, so an inexperienced guy like me could do it. Like, I don't want to pour a concrete slab and then wait a year for it to settle or something.
Here's a crappy cellphone picture, I can try getting a better one tomorrow if there's a need:


Is it a one hole or two hole?  If the ground is too soft for an outhouse, it might be better to move to harder ground.  Soft ground support might be too expensive for an outhouse/might not be the best location.

@crip659 - what holes are you talking about? There's one hole in the ground where all the waste goes...

So one hole with no company to spend the time with.  The fancy outhouses have two holes, so no waiting.

@crip659 - Ahh, no. That's some next level sh*t.

I've built about 200 latrines. You can pour a concrete slab in a day and use it the next day, no need to wait a year. They work in all types of soils. Use the wood you have to make the form, a Folgers coffee can to form the hole. Don't forget the pipe to vent it.

OK. Well... sounds kind of like an overkill, but I'll keep it in mind.

@Cherry   Good to know you've done 200  ... just in case I need one. :-)
